# CSV to JSON convert using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good afternoon, I don't have a background on python, and i tried some pre made code that is published on the internet and stack overflow but i don't get the result i want. here is my reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-csv-to-json-using-python.
maybe someone can help me with a simple code, i want to convert this csv format

| appname | hostname | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| backend | testserver1 | 1 |
| frontend | testserver2 | 2 |
| database | testserver3 | 3 |

into a json format that looks like this

```
{
  
  "appname": ["backend","frontend","database"],
  "hostname": ["testserver1","testserver2","testserver3"],
  "id": ["1","2","3"]

}
```

What im currently using:

```
import csv
import json


# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):

        # create a dictionary
        data = {}

        # Open a csv reader called DictReader
        with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
                csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

                # Convert each row into a dictionary
                # and add it to data
                for rows in csvReader:

                        # Assuming a column named 'No' to
                        # be the primary key
                        key = rows['appname']
                        data[key] = rows

        # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
        # function to dump data
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
                jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# Driver Code

# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = r'Names.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'Names.json'

# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

output from the code:

```
{
    "backend": {
        "appname": "backend",
        "hostname": "testserver1",
        "ami_id": "1"
    },
    "frontend": {
        "appname": "frontend",
        "hostname": "testserver2",
        "ami_id": "2"
    },
    "database": {
        "appname": "database",
        "hostname": "testserver3",
        "ami_id": "3"
    }
```

The result is want:

```
{
  
  "appname": ["backend","frontend","database"],
  "hostname": ["testserver1","testserver2","testserver3"],
  "id": ["1","2","3"]

}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are running yourself to the question and describe what issue you are having with it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @tzane added the details. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most Pythonic way to read CSV values into dict of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474507/most-pythonic-way-to-read-csv-values-into-dict-of-lists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert CSV file to multiline JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697846/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-multiline-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print each dictionary during `row in csvReader` loop you'll see:

```
{'appname': 'backend', 'hostname': 'testserver1', 'id': '1'}
{'appname': 'frontend', 'hostname': 'testserver2', 'id': '2'}
{'appname': 'database', 'hostname': 'testserver3', 'id': '3'}
```

So you need to modify the loop to get desired behavior:

```
        # Open a csv reader called DictReader
        with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

            # Convert each row into a dictionary
            # and add it to data
            for row in csvReader:
                for columnName in row:
                    if columnName not in data:
                        data[columnName] = []
                    data[columnName].append(row[columnName])
```

The output JSON file will look like:

```
{
    "appname": [
        "backend",
        "frontend",
        "database"
    ],
    "hostname": [
        "testserver1",
        "testserver2",
        "testserver2"
    ],
    "id": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your input file is really huge I would suggest using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
csv_df = pd.read_csv('stack_69581387.csv')

d= {'appname': csv_df.appname.tolist(),
    'hostname': csv_df.hostname.tolist(),
    'id': csv_df.id.tolist()}
```

If you want to have only unique values (it is not specified in your question what logic should be applied if you have redundancies in the data) you may use:

```py
import pandas as pd
csv_df = pd.read_csv('stack_69581387.csv')

d = {'appname': csv_df.appname.unique().tolist(),
     'hostname': csv_df.hostname.unique().tolist(),
     'id': csv_df.id.unique().tolist()}
```

And, to write it:

```
import json
with open('data_69581387.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(d, outfile)
```